# remove id from select().distinct

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this is AR on my controller

```
areas = WaterQuality.select(:area_id, :area).distinct
```

The problem is, the result always has `id` together with `area_id` and `area`. I have to do this bit to remove `id` from the result.

```
areas = WaterQuality.select(:area_id, :area).distinct

new_areas = []
areas.each do |area|
  new_area = {
    :area_id => area.area_id,
    :area    => area.area
  }
  new_areas << new_area
end

respond_with(new_areas)
```

I set the respond as `respond_to :xml, :json`

How can I have the result with only 2 attributes that I have defined without any other attributes?

Comment: `WaterQuality.pluck(:area_id, :area).uniq` - This would return an array of records. Will this work for your ?

Comment: Yea that's an array. I need key-value results like json format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this-

```
results = WaterQuality.select(:area_id, :area).distinct.as_json
results_without_id = results.each {|h| h.delete("id")}
```

This would return you an array of hashes with key/value pair.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes this is the closest solution I can have with exact output as I need. And less-line than what I have. But I am still wondering why the `id` is extracted from `distinct` while I clearly I did not mention that in `select`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit over the top for your but I've started using [`ActiveModel::Serializer`](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) a while ago and I'm very happy with it.

```
class WaterQualityDistinctSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :area_id, :area
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
WaterQuality.all.map { |record| record.slice(*%w(area_id area)).symbolize_keys }
```

Or even:

```
WaterQuality.all.map { |record| record.slice(*%w(area_id area)) }
```

This will return a slightly different hash in console, but the same json or xml.